# Groovy truth inconsistency? Why is a list not coerced to `true` with == operator?

Tags: groovy

All of the following assertions are `true`.

```
def obj = ["XXX"]
assert  true && obj // OK
assert  obj // OK
assert  ![] // OK
```

Why is coercion not working in the following one?

```
assert  true == obj // List is NOT coerced to true
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the == operator doesn't expect boolean operands.

Coercion is applied in the second case because the && operator expects boolean operands, and in the third case because assert expects a boolean operand. But the == operator accepts operands of any type and returns false if either the type or the value are different.

Comment: yes it does not, but I think it should be checking for Boolean type in the left or right comparison, to be consistent with the other operators.

Comment: @sumnulu That would actually make the == operator less consistent with the other operators, not more. The other operators use the same coercion rule for the second operand regardless of the type of the first operand. The only exceptions are the arithmetic operators which use a different coercion rule if one of the operands is non-integer.

Answer (score 1):

An empty collection is false when evaluated in a boolean context (AKA falsey), so

```
assert ![]
```

evaluates to `true` and the assertion passes.

Answer (score 0):

The '==' operator is translated to an **equals(Object o)** method call, so it works with any kind of Object, not just Boolean, so there's no reason for coercion to boolean.